# CSRF token not working when submitting form with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a simple token for CSRF prevention which works as expected when not using AJAX for submissions. But when using AJAX it keeps showing the custom error I created.

This is my function for generating the token:

```
function make_form_token() {
    $token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    return $token;
} // end CSRF token generation
```

The function is then called in a hidden field called form_token

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo make_form_token(); ?>">

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <button id="send" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn--primary type--uppercase">Send Enquiry</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The ajax then calls the php script from contact-submit.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#send" ).click(function(){
        $( "#send" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        $( ".hideloader" ).show();
        $( "#send" ).html( "Sending <img src='img/ajax-loader.gif'>" );

        var form_data = $( "#contact-form" ).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'contact-submit.php',
            data: form_data
        }).done(function(response) {
            $( "#server-results" ).hide().html(response).fadeIn("slow");
            $( "#send" ).prop("disabled", false);
            $( "#send" ).html( "Send Enquiry" );
        });
    });
});
```

contact-submit.php

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $message = "";

    if (!isset($_SESSION['token']) || $_POST['form_token'] !== $_SESSION['token']) {
        $message .= "There was an error submitting the form. Please try again later. <br/>";
    }

    if ($message) {
        echo "<div class='red-error'><b>There were errors in your form:</b> <br/>" . $message . "</div>";
    } else {    
        // send email etc. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you var_dump $_POST['form_token'] and $_SESSION['token']? Are they the same?

Comment: When trying to var_dump I get this :

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ on line 11
NULL string(44) "HBFYoXNsHS9WsBc7vds/MukXr0CR8pBFPc7WGi3JPvY="

Comment: Is your session started when the POST request reaches the server?

Comment: Ah, okay. I moved my session_start code to the contact-submit.php page instead of my functions.php page and that has removed the error. The tokens still don't match though

Comment: Then you had at least two problems. One is already solved. The other is probably that your HTML structure is generated when the POST request reaches the server. If that is the case, your HTML code calls make_form_token() and overrides $_SESSION['token'], which will then be different from $_POST['form_token']. You need to make sure that your HTML only runs if you have a POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what your problem is. Let me know if I am wrong. You have this HTML:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo make_form_token(); ?>">
<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
<button id="send" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn--primary type--uppercase">Send Enquiry</button>
</div>
</form>
```

on page load this HTML is generated, but I think this is generated on POST as well, so when you POST your `form` along with the valid `form_token` and the request reaches the server, it generates a new token (when the HTML is generated), stores it into $_SESSION and that will be different from the one it generated on page load. The solution is to generate the `form` if and only if your request is a GET.

EDIT: Make sure the session is started when the POST request reaches the server.

EDIT2: This is how you can check whether your request is a POST:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     // The request is using the POST method
}
```

Comment: But I don't understand why it doesn't work. I use this all the time for forms that don't use AJAX and it works 100%. Only now when using AJAX it gives me this problem

Comment: @Jonathan I think your HTML code which overrides the token stored in the session is called after the POST is received by the server and then it will more often than not differ from the posted value.

Comment: Thank you. If you look in my original post I already had the check for POST ( I just had one less = than you did)
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

Comment: Am I meant to move this somewhere else? 
 <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo make_form_token(); ?>">

Comment: @Jonathan you check whether the request is a POST which is correct and it is at a good place. But checking whether the request is a GET around your HTML is missing. Without that, your HTML will be generated anyway and your make_form_token will be called which will override your token stored in the session. You will need to wrap an if around your HTML and check that the request is a GET. It should improve your situation and it might be just the fix you need.

Comment: Hmm. I need to try understand this as it is confusing. I say that because this is a unique problem for me using AJAX. As I mentioned, I do this a lot without AJAX, just php and this isn't an issue. So, are you saying I need an if statement around this:  <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo make_form_token(); ?>"> checking if it's GET?

Comment: @Jonathan you probably need such a statement, as if this is executed on POST, then it will result in inconsistencies and it is a potential cause of the behavior you experienced. I understand you had no problems with POST requests without AJAX, but somehow the problem was created. I have not enough context to determine the genesis of the problem, but you surely should have no such problems. If you already made sure that the HTML is only generated in case of a GET request, then forget my suggestion. Otherwise it might be the missing puzzle.

Comment: sorry. I think I am too stupid to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: There was actually a simple solution to this. I just didn't have session_start() on all the pages.

Comment: @Jonathan when you do not understand something, do not consider yourself stupid. In that case you just lack information and research is needed. The actual solution seems to rime with the first edit of my answer though.